# Aggrid enterprise version 29 filter popup background color is coming transperent

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-validation

``
We are using aggrid enterprise version 29 in out project , by default the aggrid's filter popup background coming as transperent and its taking ag-theme-alpine ag-menu {background-color: var(--ag-control-panel-background-color, #f8f8f8);} this CSS.

i am not able to override this style through my react code . Thank you on advance for the help.

I have tried to add the style as below .
ag-theme-alpine .ag-menu {--ag-background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247) !important;background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);background-color: var(--ag-control-panel-background-color, #ffffff);}.ag-tabs ag-menu ag-focus-managed ag-ltr ag-popup-child {--ag-background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247) !important;background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);background-color: var(--ag-control-panel-background-color, #ffffff);}.ag-theme-alpine ag-popup{--ag-background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247) background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);background-color: var(--ag-control-panel-background-color, #ffffff);}

which is not working
``

Comment: Please use proper [formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193323/how-to-format-code-in-posts-on-stack-overflow).